Regular Kähler Cone Metrics
Let $C(Y)=\mathbb{R}^+\times_{r^2}Y$ be a Kähler cone with link $Y$, a $(2n-1)$-dim compact manifold. Easy computation implies that the Kähler form $\omega=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}\partial\bar{\partial}r^2$ and $\xi=J(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r})$ is the Reeb vector field on the link, and Killing, where $J$ is the complex structure.
Now the closure of the flow generated by $\xi$ in the isometry group of the link generates a holomorphic $\mathbb{T}^N$ isometric action for some real torus.
We call the cone is quasi-regular, if $N=1$ (and in particular, regular if this $S^1$-action is free).
Now I find following results about the characterization of regular Kähler cones without proofs:
(1) Any Kähler cone metric on $L^{\times}$, the contraction of the zero section of a negative line bundle $L$ over a projective manifold, with some positive multiple of the radial vector field equal to the Euler vector field on $L \backslash\{0\}$, is regular.
(2) Let $\left(C_0, \omega_0\right)$ be a regular Kähler cone with Kähler cone metric $\omega_0=\frac{i}{2} \partial \bar{\partial} r^2$, radial function $r$, and radial vector field $r \partial_r$. Then $C_0$ is biholomorphic to the blowdown $L^{\times}$of the zero section of a negative line bundle $L$ over a projective manifold $D$, with $a \cdot r \partial_r$ equal to the Euler field on $L \backslash\{0\}$ for some $a>0$.
I have some problems about these statements:
(a) Is $L^{\times}$ just $L/L_0$, where $L_0$ is the zero section? If not, what's it?
(b) What's the Euler field?
(c) What's the blowdown, is it the converse process of blowup?
Also, I hope that someone can give me the outline of the proof or give me some reference. In addition, I wonder if there is a characterization of quasi-regular Kähler cones? Thanks in advance.

The correspondence between regular Kähler cones (equivalently, regular Sasaki manifolds) and negative line bundles on Kähler manifolds is sometimes referred to as the "Boothby-Wang construction", after this paper of the two authors.
This construction is also discussed in great detail in the book "Sasakian geometry" by Boyer and Galicki, see their Theorem 6.1.26 and Theorem 7.1.3.
Hope this helps!
